# Is it possible to run kubeflow pipelines or notebooks using AWS EMR as Spark Master/Driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr, amazon-eks

I am trying to implement as solution on an EKS cluster where jobs are expected to be submitted using kubeflow central dashboard by users/developers. To include spark as a service for users on platform I tried to have standalone spark installation on EKS cluster where everything other config will have to managed by admin. So managed service EMR could be possibly used here as an independent service and will be triggered only when job is submitted.

I an trying to make EMR on EC2 or EMR on EKS available as an endpoint to be used in kubeflow notebooks or pipelines. Tried various things but could not have any robust solution for it.

So if anybody has any sort of experience in the same please feel free to drop in your suggestions.

Comment: can you describe what you've tried so far?

Comment: @JeremyCowan Are you looking for solution to this issue

Comment: No, I'm trying to help you, but there's not enough information in your original question.